# Cannot get flex box to vertically and horizontally center item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm setting up a extremely basic landing page for a friend. I haven't developed a website in a few years and I'm very out of touch. Been searching for ages but nothing seems to work. Trying to get a basic png image centered in the middle of the page.

I've tried using flexbox - `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` - and can't get it working. I've tried going back to old table cells and that didn't work. I even tried doing margin autos with set margin top but that wasn't responsive enough.

```
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
 
        height: 100vh;
```

Want the item to be centred but it only centres horizontally but not vertically. Page is here for reference www.shoeshoe.co/

Comment: give your body element height: 100vh;

Comment: @ChrisLi this is a bad idea! If you have a horizontal scroll bar then you will end up with an unintended horizontal scroll bar. https://jsfiddle.net/ynh5uwte/

Comment: @Aaron3219 what are you saying

Comment: Sorry, had a word wrong. What I meant is: this is a bad idea! If you have a horizontal scroll bar then you will end up with an unintended vertical scroll bar. You can see it in my fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/ynh5uwte/show/

Comment: your fiddle have no markup but i see what you mean, if this becomes a problem then switch to height: 100%

Answer (score 1):

Your settings are correct - you just need to put it into the right context:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50/fa0">
</div>
```

Comment: @Aaron3219 I am not talking about the cleanest solution ( I also would use 100% height on html, body and the wrapper element), I am just showing that the code in the question works fine if it is put into the proper context.